# sldata doesn't work in Silverlight API 3.0

Tags: silverlight, arcgis-server

I have inestaled arcgis server Silverlight API 3.0 and I want to have identify in my map toolbar

here is some part of my codes

```
<slData:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"  HeadersVisibility="None" Background="White">
        <slData:DataGrid.Columns>
  <slData:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}"   FontWeight="Bold"/>
  <slData:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </slData:DataGrid.Columns>
</slData:DataGrid>
```

but  dosnt work and an error occured that the "type sldata:datagrid was not found. veryfye that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all references assemplies have been build"

I tried to add all esri assemblies but my problem didnt solve

does anyone knows how can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll

also make sure sldata is defined in your xmlns mappings.

btw this has absolutely nothing to do with the esri assemblies, since this is all part of microsoft's stuff.